# How to match live camera image with an image

Tags: java, android, camera, match, live

Is there any way to match live camera image with an image?

For an example, I want to call a function when a number of fingers are displayed.

Comment: You don't need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an open source computer vision library, called **OpenCV** :

> OpenCV is released under a BSD license, it is free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and soon Java interfaces running on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac. The library has >2500 optimized algorithms (see figure below). It is used around the world, has >2.5M downloads and >40K people in the user group. Uses range from interactive art, to mine inspection, stitching maps on the web on through advanced robotics.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/